# Can't round a custom-made function

Tags: r, function, rounding

I have this data

```
dput(per_stack[1:4,])
```

which gives this output:

```
structure(list(articles_ponderats2_migpunts = c(20.2083333333333, 
20.6666666666667, 23.8333333333333, 15.1666666666667), Tramspoblacio = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1 - 999", "1000 - 4999", "5000 - 9999", 
"10000 - 19999", "20000 - 49999", "50000 - 99999", "100000 - 200000", 
"Mayor de 200000"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created a custom-made function for doing the summary

```
funcio_resum <-function(x) {
  n<-NROW(x)
  mean<-mean(x)
  median <- median (x)
  min<-min (x)
  max<-max(x)
  q1 <- quantile(x, .25)
  q3 <- quantile(x, .75)
  SD<- sd(x)
  IQR <- IQR(x)
  quantile <- quantile(x, probs=seq(.1,.9, by =.1))
  hist<-hist(x)
  summary<-list(n=n,mean=mean, median = median, max=max,min=min, SD=SD, IQR = IQR)
  return(summary)
}
```

Then I apply it and afterwards transform it to a table

```
resum <- tapply(index_articles_migpunts$articles_ponderats2_migpunts, index_articles_migpunts$Tramspoblacio, funcio_resum)
resum <- do.call (rbind, resum)
```

It works, but the numbers are not round. When I apply it later with dplyr

```
resum %>% round(digits = 2)
```

it says

```
"Error in round(., digits = 2) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function".
```

I thought this anwswer is given because there is an histogram in the function, so
then I've tried to round the mathematical arguments (mean, etc.) in the function itself. However, it rounds the results to the integer whole number (i.e: 8 instead of 7, 88, etc.) in spite of having written "digits = 2 "

```
funcio_resum <-function(x) {
 n<-NROW(x) 
 mean<- round(mean(x, digits = 2)) 
 median <- round(median (x, digits = 2)) 
  min<-min (x)
  max<-max(x)
  q1 <- quantile(x, .25)
  q3 <- quantile(x, .75)
  SD<- sd(x)
  IQR <- IQR(x)
  quantile <- quantile(x, probs=seq(.1,.9, by =.1))
  hist<-hist(x)
  summary<-list(n=n,mean=mean, median = median, max=max,min=min, SD=SD, IQR = IQR)
  return(summary)
}
```

Why it does not work properly?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What is the structure of `resum` just before you run `resum %>% round(digits = 2)`?  Can you `pdut(head(resum))` there?

Comment: you are doing `round(mean(x, digits = 2))`, try putting the digits param outside of mean(), like this: `round(mean(x), digits = 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are passing the `digits` param into `mean()` instead of `round()`.

I've tried this locally and it works as expected:

```r
> round(mean(c(1,2,3)), digits = 2)
[1] 2
```

Hope it helps!